# Probabilities of elections

Tags: statistics

Suppose that $30\%$, $50\%$, and $20\%$ of people in an area are conservatives, liberals, and independents, respectively. Records show that in the recent election $65\%$ of conservatives, $82\%$ of Liberals, and $50\%$ of Independents voted. If a person is selected at random and it turns out they did not vote in the election, what is the probability they are Liberal?

The way I approached it is $30\%+50\%+20\%=100\%$

$100- 82\%$ liberals voted $= 18\%$??

Comment: So 10.5% were non-voting conservatives, 9% were non-voting liberals, 10% were non-voting independents. You want the chance a non-voter is liberal.

Comment: Are you familiar with Bayes? If so then this is your chance to apply it.

Answer (score 1):

As drhab said, you  need to use [Bayes' theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem).

If we let the event $V$=voted in the election, and $L$=is a liberal, the we can frame the problem as:

$P(L|\neg V)=\frac{P(L)P(\neg V|L)}{P(L)P(\neg V|L)+P(C)P(\neg V|C)+P(I)P(\neg V|I)}=\frac{0.5(1-.82)}{0.5(1-.82)+0.3(1-.65)+0.2(1-0.5)} = \frac{0.09}{0.295}= 0.31$

What you calculated was the proportion of Liberals that didn't vote, but you need the proporation of non-voters that are liberal, so you were using the wrong base population (not liberals, but non-voters).